# Setting up JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu to point to Window's JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, ubuntu

I tried to run Kafka on CMD in Windows and it's very unstable , constantly giving errors. Then I came across this [post](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/), which suggests installing Ubuntu and run Kafka from there.

I have installed Ubuntu successfully. Given that I have already defined `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231` as one of the environmental variables and CMD recognizes this variable but Ubuntu does not, I am wondering how to make Ubuntu recognize this because at the moment, when i typed `java -version`, Ubuntu returns `command not found`.

**Update:** Please note that I have to have Ubuntu's `JAVA_HOME` pointing to  the evironmental variable `JAVA_HOME` defined in my Window system. Because my Java program in eclipse would need to talk to Kafka using the same JVM.

I have added the two lines below in my `/etc/profile` file. `echo $JAVA_HOME` returns the correct path. However, `java -version` returns a different version of Java installed on Ubuntu, not the one defined in the `/etc/profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_231
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I suppose you installed ubuntu via WSL. You should consider it a completely separate operating system and install openjdk via `apt`.

Comment: oh i seee. I didn't know that i have to treat it as a completely different system. In that case, would my java program running in eclipse still be able to talk to Kafka server opened in Ubuntu ?

Comment: As a side note, `JAVA_HOME` doesn't tell the operating system where the `java` executable is. That's what `PATH` is for.

Comment: About your latest edit, changes in `/etc/profile` take effect either after you log back in or if you `source /etc/profile`. Have you done any of those?

Comment: Hi @FedericoklezCulloca, I edited the `export JAVA_HOME=mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_231`  in /etc/profile and have restarted the machine and logged back  on but it's still showing a different version of Java, which I installed in Ubuntu earlier by running `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk -y`

Comment: What's the output of `which java`?

Comment: i just removed the Java installed on Ubuntu with `sudo apt remove --autoremove openjdk-8-*`. So `which java` returns nothing now.

Comment: When i type `whereis java`. It returns 3 paths. The last one is showing `mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_231`. Yet when i tpyed java, it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues. Firstly you omitted the "/" from the beginning of the environment variable so your `JAVA_HOME` would not work unless you `cd /` as "mnt" won't exist.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_231
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Secondly, if you use a Windows JDK the executable is `java.exe`

```
java.exe -version
```

Also consider when using WSL that WSL1 is faster when accessing Windows OS disk - helpful if using `java.exe`, and that WSL2 is faster for Linux mount drives - and you may be better off using Linux binaries in favour of Windows binaries as suggested in your Kafka post.

Comment: I followed your solution above and managed to have Ubuntu locate Java in my local machine.  Then I tried to `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` and it returned 
`/home/Me/kafka_2.13-2.8.1/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 330: /mnt/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_231/bin/java: No such file or directory`. I am guessing this error came up because i am running Window binaries and Kafka shell script would require me to use the Linux binaries. Am i right ?

Comment: As per the post, it does look like you need the Linux binaries not cross-over to Windows

Comment: In that case, since my Java program that runs Kafka runs on eclipse , I would have to have eclipse point to the Linux's JDK . Am I correct ?

Comment: @user1769197 why do you think you need to run kafka and your project on the same virtual machine? Isn't kafka a service you could potentially even run on a completely different physical machine?

Answer (score 1):

When the user logs in, the environment will be loaded from the /etc/profile and $HOME/.bashrc files.
There are many ways to solve this problem. You can execute ex manually

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_66
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

or fix the configuration in /etc/profile or $HOME/.bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_66
export JRE_HOME=$JAVA_HOME/jre
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/lib:$JRE_HOME/lib:$CLASSPATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `/etc/profile`, append

```
export JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231

export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: This will not work as C: drive is not recognised, and you have set JAVA_HOME to `C:Program FilesJavajdk1.8.0_231` because `\` means escape next char on Linux